# Address the correct this context in javascript when declaring functions outside of constructor

Tags: javascript, angular

It's production code so I can't show it, but here's the gist of it:

```
function constructorHere() {
  / * js code * /
};

constructorHere.prototype.functionHere = function () {
  this.blah = 1; // 'this' needs to refer to constructorHere, not the caller context
  / * more js code * /
};
```

I'm not sure how to get this to refer to the correct context. It seems to work fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but not in IE. I've tried stuff like

```
function constructorHere() {
  constructorHere._this = this; // or this._this = this;
  / * rest of js code * /
};

constructorHere.prototype.functionHere = function() {
  constructorHere._this =  ...; // problem: constructor._this would 
                                // always be the latest instance
};
```

and a few variants of the same idea, but of course the instance would only be the latest instance. Is my only option at this point to move all the function declarations into the constructor? Thanks!

Comment: The value of `this` always depends on how you call the method. Show that part of your code to us, please.

Comment: the call is 
`var newC = new constructorHere();
 newC.functionHere();`
which make it all the more confusing since the context should seem correct to me, unless it doesn't take from newC in that case.

Comment: Well your first code *does* work with that call, even in Internet Explorer (`this` does refer to `newC` of course, not to `constructorHere`). You really need to make a [mcve] of the problem.

Comment: I'm actually unable to reproduce it without the actual code base itself, so I think I'll have to figure it out myself. Thank you for that article though, I'll keep it in mind for future postings. Thanks!